# Segmentation Fault trying to use result of convexityDefects

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, openni

i'm trying to do a C++ program for fingertip recognition using kinect with the libraries OpenNi and OpenCV 2.4.

Here i list my main function (I intentionally avoided to write down here other function/classes that probably are not cause of the error):

```
// xml to initialize OpenNI
#define SAMPLE_XML_PATH "/home/jacopo/workspace/opencv_fingertip_detector/Sample-Tracking.xml"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    XnStatus rc = XN_STATUS_OK;
    xn::EnumerationErrors errors;

    // Initialize OpenNI
    rc = g_Context.InitFromXmlFile(SAMPLE_XML_PATH, g_ScriptNode, &errors);
    CHECK_ERRORS(rc, errors, "InitFromXmlFile");
    CHECK_RC(rc, "InitFromXmlFile");

    rc = g_Context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_DEPTH, g_DepthGenerator);
    CHECK_RC(rc, "Find depth generator");
    rc = g_Context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_HANDS, g_HandsGenerator);
    CHECK_RC(rc, "Find hands generator");
    rc = g_Context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_GESTURE, g_GestureGenerator);
    CHECK_RC(rc, "Find gesture generator");

    XnCallbackHandle h;
    if (g_HandsGenerator.IsCapabilitySupported(XN_CAPABILITY_HAND_TOUCHING_FOV_EDGE))
    {
        g_HandsGenerator.GetHandTouchingFOVEdgeCap().RegisterToHandTouchingFOVEdge(TouchingCallback, NULL, h);
    }

    XnCallbackHandle hGestureIntermediateStageCompleted, hGestureProgress, hGestureReadyForNextIntermediateStage;
    g_GestureGenerator.RegisterToGestureIntermediateStageCompleted(GestureIntermediateStageCompletedHandler, NULL, hGestureIntermediateStageCompleted);
    g_GestureGenerator.RegisterToGestureReadyForNextIntermediateStage(GestureReadyForNextIntermediateStageHandler, NULL, hGestureReadyForNextIntermediateStage);
    g_GestureGenerator.RegisterGestureCallbacks(NULL, GestureProgressHandler, NULL, hGestureProgress);


    // Create NITE objects
    g_pSessionManager = new XnVSessionManager;
    rc = g_pSessionManager->Initialize(&g_Context, "Click,Wave", "RaiseHand");
    CHECK_RC(rc, "SessionManager::Initialize");

    g_pSessionManager->RegisterSession(NULL, SessionStarting, SessionEnding, FocusProgress);

    g_pDrawer = new XnVPointDrawer(20, g_DepthGenerator);
    g_pFlowRouter = new XnVFlowRouter;
    g_pFlowRouter->SetActive(g_pDrawer);

    g_pSessionManager->AddListener(g_pFlowRouter);

    g_pDrawer->RegisterNoPoints(NULL, NoHands);
    g_pDrawer->SetDepthMap(g_bDrawDepthMap);

    // Initialization done. Start generating
    rc = g_Context.StartGeneratingAll();
    CHECK_RC(rc, "StartGenerating");

    cv::Mat depthshow;
    int key_pre = 0 ;

    for( ; ; )
    {
        if (key_pre == 27)
            break ;
        XnMapOutputMode mode;
        g_DepthGenerator.GetMapOutputMode(mode);

        g_Context.WaitOneUpdateAll(g_DepthGenerator);

        //TEST
        g_DepthGenerator.GetMetaData(depthMD);
        XnDepthPixel* pDepth = depthMD.WritableData();

        // Update NITE tree
        g_pSessionManager->Update(&g_Context);

        if(g_pDrawer->handFound)
        {
            for (XnUInt y = 0; y < depthMD.YRes(); ++y)
            {
                for (XnUInt x = 0; x < depthMD.XRes(); ++x, ++pDepth)
                {

                    if (*pDepth>g_pDrawer->pt3D.Z+50 || *pDepth<g_pDrawer->pt3D.Z-50)
                    {
                        *pDepth=0;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        //for opencv Mat
        cv::Mat depth16(480,640,CV_16SC1,(unsigned short*)depthMD.WritableData());

        //convert depth 11 bit image 2 8 bit image
        //depth16.convertTo(depthshow,CV_8U,-255/4096.0,255);
        depth16.convertTo(depthshow, CV_8UC1, 0.025);

        if(g_pDrawer->handFound)
        {
            cv::Point handPos(g_pDrawer->ptProjective.X, g_pDrawer->ptProjective.Y);
            cv::circle(depthshow, handPos, 5, cv::Scalar(0xffff), 10, 8, 0);
            Mat src_gray;
            int thresh = 10;
            RNG rng(12345);

            blur( depthshow, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

            Mat threshold_output;
            vector<vector<Point> > contours;
            vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

            /// Detect edges using Threshold
            threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );

            /// Find contours
            findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

            /// Find the convex hull object for each contour
            vector<vector<int> > hullsI (contours.size());
            vector<vector<Point> >  hullsP (contours.size() );
            vector<vector<Vec4i> >  defects (contours.size() );

            for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                convexHull(contours[i], hullsI[i], false, false);
                convexHull(contours[i], hullsP[i], false, true);
                if (contours[i].size() >3 )
                {
                    convexityDefects(contours[i], hullsI[i], defects[i]);
                }
            }

            /// Draw contours + hull results
            Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

            for( int i = 0; i < defects.size(); i++)
            {
                Vec4i defect(defects[i][0]);
                Point start = contours[i][defect[0]];
                Point end = contours[i][defect[1]];
                Point far = contours[i][defect[2]];
                std::cout << "Roba mia: "<< start << "\t" << end << "\t" << far << std::endl;
                line(drawing, start, end, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 1);
                circle(drawing, far, 5, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 1);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                Scalar color = Scalar( 255, 0, 0 );
                drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
                drawContours( drawing, hullsP, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
            }

            /// Show in a window
            namedWindow( "Hull demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
            imshow( "Hull demo", drawing );

        }

        cv::imshow("PrimeSense Nite Point Viewer", depthshow);
        key_pre = cv::waitKey(33);

    }
    cv::destroyWindow("PrimeSense Nite Point Viewer");
    CleanupExit();
    return 0;
}
```

The segmentation fault happen when i try to use one of the variable `start`, `end` or `far`, indeed if I comment the three lines (`std::cout`, `line` and `circle`) right after I assign the three variables the code run normally without problems.

Does someone of you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks for reading

J.

Comment: Is there a difference between cv::Point and Point? Is Point a class you wrote or part of openCV?

Comment: Is the same i just wrote on the source file using namespace cv

Comment: What happens if you comment those lines, but print `contours[i][defect[0]]`, `contours[i][defect[1]]` and `contours[i][defect[2]]` instead of printing `start`, `end`, `far`?

Comment: Segmentation fault so the problem is there but i cannot understand how retrieve the values from the indexes i got with convexityDefects ...

Comment: Try checking contours[i].size(). The vector is probably empty.

Comment: Also try printing the values of "defect[0]", defect[1]", and "defect[2]".

Comment: i post some result of the print of contours[i].size(): Size: 57
Size: 21
Size: 36
Size: 6855311
Size: 0
Size: 6850698
Size: 18446743817092149477
Size: 18446744073709551609
Size: 536870911 i'm totally lost since i can't understand why it could be zero or even so big number

Comment: For defect print i had this before having again segmentation fault: Defect: 124   138   134
Defect: 3   7   4
Defect: 251   253   252

Comment: i found also an example in python but i really don't know hot to port it in C++. Here is the link http://dip4fish.blogspot.fr/2012/07/convexity-defects-in-cluster-of-mouse.html where at the end of the listing there is a way to obtain those values from defects